# what is the difference between managed heap and GC heap

Tags: .net, clr, vmmap

Can anyone explain to me the difference between managed heap and GC heap? Since I noticed that sometimes the total managed heap size < (Gen 0 + Gen 1 + Gen 2 + LOH) in Process explorer + VMMap.

In my mind the total managed heap should be equal GC heap(Gen0-2+LOH),why in the .NET Performance tab of Process explorer, the total GC heap size is larger than the managed heap size in VMMap?

Comment: I'd guess the difference is memory that's not actually in use at the moment, but hasn't been given back to the OS.

Comment: I agree with you, but I'm still confused that if there are some unreferenced objects in GC heap, what is that in VMMap? I guess it will be as private data or native heap, it that true?

Answer (score 4):

```
GC HEAP
```

GC Heap hosts object instances and Generations are the logical view of the garbage collector heap

```
MANAGED HEAP
```

A managed heap segment is a chunk of memory that the garbage collector 
 reserves from the OS (via calling VirtualAlloc) on behalf of managed code

```
LOADER HEAP
```

LoaderHeaps hold together the type system it is further divided in 
1> High frequency heap 
2> low frequency heap 
3> Stub Heap

you can also use SOS to verify these heap

!eeheap -loader

!eeheap - GC

!GCRoot [-nostacks] [object reference]